# SQL Server 2014 Express Edition: silent install

Tags: sql-server

We are trying to install in silent mode the **Express** Edition of SQL Server 2014 SP2 using an installer that can be downloaded from the Microsoft Evaluation Center. This is the download link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2014-sp2/

This installer gives the following possibilities:

- Select the Express edition
- Select the Evaluation edition (valid for 180 days)
- Insert a license for an Enterprise or Standard Edition

I need to install SQL Server 2014 SP2 Express Edition in silent mode, using the command line parameters and/or a configuration file with the correct options.

However, we cannot find information about which option should be included in the command line or in the configuration file to select Express Edition instead of the Enterprise Edition for Evaluation (by default, the Evaluation option is selected).

This is the script we are using to install SQL Server 2014 SP2 in silent mode (it installs SQL Server in Enterprise Evaluation mode):

```
Setup.exe /Q ^
          /action=Install ^
          /ERRORREPORTING=1 ^
          /INDICATEPROGRESS=true ^
          /TCPENABLED=1 ^
          /SKIPRULES=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck ^
          /features="SQLEngine, FullText, SSMS, ADV_SSMS, SNAC_SDK" ^
          /INSTANCENAME=GEMINIS ^
          /INSTALLSQLDATADIR="C:\SQL SERVER 2014" ^
          /INSTANCEDIR="C:\SQL SERVER 2014" ^
          /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" ^
          /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic ^
          /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" ^
          /AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Disabled ^
          /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS ^
          /ROLE=AllFeatures_WithDefaults ^
          /SECURITYMODE=SQL ^
          /SAPWD="password37" ^
          /SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
```

Once the installation process has finished, the SQL Server is in Enterprise Evaluation mode.

What do we have to change in the command line or in the configuration file to install the Express edtion?

Just to clarify my problem, we have to deliver a installer to our customer. This installer must deploy several SW components in silent mode. One of these SW components is SQL Server 2014 SP2.

This installer will provide to the customer the possibility to select Express or Enterprise Evaluation. He will make the decision depending on his license availability.

So now, we have two different options:

**Option 1:** Integrate in our installer two different installers for SQL Server 2014 SP2, one for Express and other for Enterprise and, depending on the customer choice, use the right installer.

**Option 2:** Integrate in our installer only the SQL Server 2014 SP2 downloaded from the link at the beginning of the post and, depending on the customer choice, use this installer with the right set of parameters.

The advantage of Option 2 is basically the size. With this option, our installer will have integrated only one SQL Server installer instead of two with option 1. This means:

- less time to compile and build our installer
- less time to test the installer
- less time to handle the installer
- less space to store it
- ...

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: You would start by downloading SQL Server Express, not SQL Server 2014. In essence you have downloaded the wrong thing.

Comment: Unless you want to install on Windows Server 2008 R2, you should probably download a newer version of SQL Server Express too.

Comment: The problem we have is that sometimes we have to install Express and sometimes we have to install an Enterprise Evaluation so this Evaluation installer we downloaded is the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-2014) for available options. You can also try direct Express Edition [installation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53167) link. I just downloaded SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe 314MB file from the second link. Unpacked it in some temp folder and run the same code above but with stronger password like gqmPv4eSbcJhj2wScN instead of password37 because that will fail. 5 minutes down the road you'll get your database installed with your script.

```
Setup.exe /Q ^
          /action=Install ^
          /ERRORREPORTING=1 ^
          /INDICATEPROGRESS=true ^
          /TCPENABLED=1 ^
          /SKIPRULES=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck ^
          /features="SQLEngine, FullText, SSMS, ADV_SSMS, SNAC_SDK" ^
          /INSTANCENAME=GEMINIS ^
          /INSTALLSQLDATADIR="C:\SQL SERVER 2014" ^
          /INSTANCEDIR="C:\SQL SERVER 2014" ^
          /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" ^
          /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic ^
          /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" ^
          /AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Disabled ^
          /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS ^
          /ROLE=AllFeatures_WithDefaults ^
          /SECURITYMODE=SQL ^
          /SAPWD="gqmPv4eSbcJhj2wScN" ^
          /SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
```

Comment: Thanks Dalibor....basically your link is the same we have been using during these days. The problem is that in this link there is no information about how to select the edition (Express or Enterprise Evaluation) using the installer we downloaded from the Evaluation Center.

Comment: So I just downloaded SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe 314MB file from the second link. Unpacked it in some temp folder and run the same code above but with stronger password like gqmPv4eSbcJhj2wScN instead of password37 because that will fail. 5 minutes down the road you'll get your database installed with your script.

Comment: Thanks again Dalibor... we know the script works with  SQL Server Express installer (we tested it), but we want to avoid to download two SQL Server installers, one for Express edition and other for the Enterprise Evaluation Edition. Our idea is to use just one (the Evaluation Edition installer) and use it to install Express or Enterprise Evaluation. It is possible to do this using the non-silent mode by selecting **Express** or **Evaluation** option in the first step of the installation process, but it seems that this selection it is not possible using the command line or a configuration file.

Comment: I'm also not sure it is possible but I'm interested maybe someone knows workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but you might be able to accomplish this with a response/configuration file.

Details are here...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-using-a-configuration-file?view=sql-server-ver15

You basically run the install to generate a configuration file.

```
SETUP.exe /UIMODE=Normal /ACTION=INSTALL
```

After you answer all the prompts you are provided the location of the configuration file at the "Ready to Install" step.

[Install Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9I77.jpg)

You can cancel the install once you have the configuration file.  Then you deploy the configuration file and execute the installer referencing the configuration file on the command line.

```
Setup.exe /ConfigurationFile=MyConfigurationFile.INI
```

You can still use commend line options and they will override settings in the configuration file.

That *might* capture the additional option that is not documented.

I have not tested with your specific issue.  But it might be worth a try.